# Node.js Image Optimization Service Using Sharp Library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've developed an image optimization service in Node.js, leveraging the [Sharp library](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) for image processing. The service is designed to handle various image formats, offering resizing and format conversion features.

I'm looking for feedback on the overall structure, performance optimization, and best practices in my implementation.

The code includes HTTP server setup, request handling, image processing using Sharp, and error management. I'm particularly interested in improving the efficiency and reliability of the service. Below is the core part of my implementation.

My node.js code (https://github.com/dchochol/image-optimization/tree/main/src):

*index.js*

```
/**
 * This script sets up an HTTP server to handle image optimization requests.
 * It leverages the ImageRequest and ImageHandler classes to process images.
 * The server listens on a specified port, receives image requests, and sends back optimized images.
 */

// Required modules and classes
const ImageRequest= require('./ImageRequest.js');
const ImageHandler= require('./ImageHandler.js')

/**
 * Retrieves the server port number from environment variables or uses a default value (.env/fly.toml file).
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

/**
 * Creates an HTTP server.
 * The server listens for image requests, processes them, and returns optimized images.
 */
const server = require('http').createServer(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Skip the favicon request.
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    // Initialize ImageRequest and ImageHandler with the incoming request.
    const imageRequest = new ImageRequest(req);
    const imageHandler = new ImageHandler(imageRequest);

    // Process the image request and get the optimized image.
    const processedRequest = await imageHandler.process();

    // Set the content type header and write the optimized image to the response.
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': processedRequest.ContentType
    });
    res.write(processedRequest.Body);
  } catch (error) {
    // Log and send an error message in case of failure.
    console.error(error);
    res.writeHead(500);
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      res.write("Internal Server Error: " + error.message);
    } else {
      res.write("Internal Server Error: " + error.toString());
    }
  }
  // End of response.
  res.end();
});

/**
 * Start listening on the specified port.
 * The server is accessible on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

*ImageRequest.js*

```
/**
 * This script includes a class for handling image requests.
 * It fetches an image from a given URL and returns it as a buffer.
 * The class uses the Node.js standard 'https' module for HTTP requests,
 * the 'qs' module for query string parsing, and the 'url' module for URL parsing.
 */

// Required libraries
const url = require('node:url');
const qs = require('qs');
const https = require('https');

/**
 * Class representing an image request.
 */
class ImageRequest {

  /**
   * Create an ImageRequest instance.
   * @param {object} request - The HTTP request object.
   */
  constructor(request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  /**
   * Extracts query parameters from the request URL.
   * Mainly used to get parameters for the Sharp image optimizer.
   * @return {Promise<object>} A promise that resolves to the query parameters object.
   */
  async getQueryParams() {
    // Parse request data from URL.
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(this.request.url);
    return Promise.resolve(qs.parse(parsedUrl.query));
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the original image from the specified URL.
   * Attempts to download the image up to a specified number of retries.
   * @param {number} maxRetries - Maximum number of retries for downloading the image.
   * @param {number} retryDelay - Delay in milliseconds between retries.
   * @return {Promise<object>} A promise that resolves to an object containing the image buffer and its content type.
   * @throws Will throw an error if the image URL is not provided or if the download fails after the maximum retries.
   */
  async getOriginalImage(maxRetries = 3, retryDelay = 250) {
    this.urlQueryParams = await this.getQueryParams();

    if (!('url' in this.urlQueryParams)) {
      throw new Error('Image is not exists.');
    }

    for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= maxRetries; attempt++) {
      try {
        const result = await this.loadImage(this.urlQueryParams.url);
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        if (attempt === maxRetries) {
          throw error;
        }
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, retryDelay));
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Loads the image from the specified URL.
   * @param {string} url - The URL of the image to be downloaded.
   * @return {Promise<object>} A promise that resolves to an object containing the image buffer and its content type.
   * @throws Will throw an error if the image download fails.
   */
  loadImage(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https.get(url, response => {
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
          reject(new Error(`Failed to download image: ${response.statusCode}`));
          return;
        }

        const chunks = [];
        response.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
        response.on('end', () => {
          const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
          resolve({ buffer, contentType: response.headers['content-type'] });
        });
      }).on('error', err => reject(err));
    });
  }
}

module.exports = ImageRequest;
```

*ImageHandler.js*

```
/**
 * This script includes a class for handling image processing requests.
 * It uses worker threads to process images, allowing image processing tasks
 * to be executed in parallel without blocking the main thread.
 * The class is designed to work with an ImageRequest instance to retrieve images.
 */

// Required libraries and classes
const ImageRequest = require('./ImageRequest');
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');

/**
 * Class representing an image handler for processing images.
 */
class ImageHandler {

  /**
   * Create an ImageHandler instance.
   * @param {ImageRequest} request - An instance of ImageRequest to handle image fetching.
   */
  constructor(request) {
    if (!(request instanceof ImageRequest)) {
      throw new Error('Expected request of type ImageRequest');
    }
    this.request = request;
  }

  /**
   * Processes the image request and outputs a modified image.
   * This method fetches the image using the ImageRequest instance and then
   * uses a worker thread to process the image.
   * @return {Promise<object>} A promise that resolves to an object containing the processed image buffer and its content type.
   * @throws Will throw an error if there is any issue in fetching the image or processing it in the worker thread.
   */
  async process () {
    // Fetch the original image and its content type
    const { buffer, contentType } = await this.request.getOriginalImage();
    delete this.request.urlQueryParams['url'];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Create a new worker thread for image processing
      const worker = new Worker(__dirname + '/imageWorker.js');

      // Post the image buffer and optimization parameters to the worker
      worker.postMessage({ buffer, imgOptimizeParams: this.request.urlQueryParams });

      // Handle messages received from the worker
      worker.on('message', (message) => {
        if (message.error) {
          reject(new Error(message.error));
        } else {
          resolve({
            Body: message.bufferImage,
            ContentType: contentType
          });
        }
      });

      // Handle any errors that occur in the worker
      worker.on('error', reject);

      // Handle worker thread exit
      worker.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
          console.error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`);
          reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = ImageHandler;
```

*imageWorker.js*

```
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
const sharp = require('sharp');

parentPort.on('message', async (task) => {
  try {
    // Perform image processing
    const sharpObject = sharp(task.buffer);

    /**
     * RESIZE
     */
    // If the request data specifies a size, resize the image.
    if ('size' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      let fitImageValue = sharp.fit.inside;
      if ('fit' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
        switch (task.imgOptimizeParams.fit) {
          case 'cover':
            fitImageValue = sharp.fit.cover;
            break;
          case 'contain':
            fitImageValue = sharp.fit.contain;
            break;
          case 'fill':
            fitImageValue = sharp.fit.fill;
            break;
          case 'outside':
            fitImageValue = sharp.fit.outside;
            break;
        }
      }
      
      let positionOfImage ='centre';
      if ('position' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
        positionOfImage = task.imgOptimizeParams.position;
      }

      let resizeWidth = 0;
      let resizeHeight = 0;
      if (task.imgOptimizeParams.size === 'width') {
        const metadata = await sharpObject.metadata();
        resizeWidth = resizeHeight = metadata.width;
      } else if (task.imgOptimizeParams.size === 'height') {
        const metadata = await sharpObject.metadata();
        resizeWidth = resizeHeight = metadata.height;
      } else {
        resizeWidth = parseInt(task.imgOptimizeParams.size.split('x')[0]);
        resizeHeight = parseInt(task.imgOptimizeParams.size.split('x')[1]);
      }

      sharpObject.resize(
        resizeWidth,
        resizeHeight,
        {fit: fitImageValue, position: positionOfImage}
      );
    }

    /**
     * CHANGE FORMAT
     */
    // If the request data specifies a format, convert the image to that format.
    if ('format' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      let quality = 100;
      if ('quality' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
        quality = parseInt(task.imgOptimizeParams.quality);
      }
      // @TODO check formats
      sharpObject.toFormat(task.imgOptimizeParams.format, {quality: quality, lossless: true});
      this.contentType = 'image/' + sharpObject.options.formatOut;
    }

    /**
     * FLIP
     */
    if ('flip' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      sharpObject.flip()
    }

    /**
     * FLOP
     */
    if ('flop' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      sharpObject.flop()
    }

    /**
     * ROTATE
     */
    if ('rotate' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      sharpObject.rotate(parseInt(task.imgOptimizeParams.rotate));
    }

    /**
     * MEDIAN
     */
    if ('median' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      sharpObject.median(parseInt(task.imgOptimizeParams.median))
    }

    /**
     * BLUR
     */
    if ('blur' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      sharpObject.blur(parseFloat(task.imgOptimizeParams.blur));
    }

    /**
     * GRAYSCALE
     */
    if ('greyscale' in task.imgOptimizeParams) {
      sharpObject.greyscale()
    }

    const outputBuffer = await sharpObject.toBuffer();

    // Send processed image back to the main thread
    parentPort.postMessage({ bufferImage: outputBuffer, error: null });
  } catch (error) {
    parentPort.postMessage({ bufferImage: null, error: error.message });
  }
});
```

I call my service (e.g.):
http://localhost:8080/?url=https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg&format=webp&quality=50&size=500x500

I've implemented the service following the standard practices in Node.js and Sharp documentation. The service functions as intended, but I haven't been able to thoroughly benchmark its performance under different loads or with various image types.

I expected my implementation to be efficient and robust, but I am unsure if there are better or more optimized ways to handle image processing in Node.js, especially using Sharp. I am also curious if my error handling and async patterns are optimally implemented.

Comment: Not enough as an answer, hence a comment. At least your index.js is very chatty. You basically write most lines twice: once as a comment, then as code. It is exactly clear from code what calling the constructor of ```ImageRequest``` does, no need to prefix that with a comment stating that you are creating an ImageRequest. This same pattern goes on all throughout the index file.